# The same rewrite rules for many directories

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a bunch of websites that share the same rewrite rules.

Every website has it's own domain, own vhost in Apache and own folder with public files. The folders use the `/var/www/<domain>/` pattern, ie. `/var/www/mydomain.com/`

My old setup contained separate .htaccess file in folder of every website. However, the new system has .htaccess disabled for performance reasons and I need to move rewrites to config files.

I do not want to create a bunch of `<Directory>` blocks having exactly the same rewrite rules. I would to create a single block which applies the rules to all websites in `/var/www/` directory.

I tried the following code:

```
<Directory /var/www/*>
RewriteEngine On
ErrorDocument 404 /404redirect.php
RewriteRule ^image.php/$ /image.php [L]
RewriteRule ^trial/$ /trial.php [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css|png|sqlite)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/$ /player.php [L]
</Directory>
```

Nothing works beside `ErrorDocument` which properly uses 404redirect.php. All of the rest rules does not work and produces 404 error.

This same code works perfectly if I use it directly, ie. in `<Directory /var/www/mydomain.com/>`.

I am quite newb in rewrites. Can somebody point me how I can get this working?

Thank you very much for everybody taking time on this, in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apache config's rewrite rules need leading slash. Try this code:

```
<Directory /var/www/*>
RewriteEngine On

ErrorDocument 404 /404redirect.php

RewriteRule ^/image.php/$ /image.php [L]

RewriteRule ^/trial/$ /trial.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css|png|sqlite)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ /player.php [L]

</Directory>
```

Don't forget to restart Apache after the change.

Comment: You was right, now it works perfect, as expected. Thank you very much Anubhava.